# Use Lerp Position and Slerp Rotation together (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, lerp

This is what I try to do, When I click on a UI Element, the camera smoothly rotate (to look at the target) and simultaneously move on top of the target.

To perform that I use a two Coroutine one for the Lerp Position and the other one for the Slerp Rotation.

The issue is that the rotation doesn't work correctly, normally the camera should look down to see the top of the target but instead of doing this it look like the Camera first look at the target and after that move to his position.

I hope this is understandable ;)

Here is the code c#

```
Vector3 LocationProjectForPos = new Vector3(Loc_X, 100, Loc_Z);
Vector3 LocationProjectForRot = new Vector3(Loc_X, Loc_Y, Loc_Z);
Vector3 MainCameraPos = MainCamera.transform.position;

if(!IsCameraMoving & LocationProjectForPos != MainCameraPos)
        {
            StartCoroutine (CoroutineMovePositionCamera(LocationProjectForPos));
            StartCoroutine (CoroutineMoveRotationCamera(LocationProjectForRot));
        }
    }
```

Moving the position of the Camera with Lerp

```
public IEnumerator CoroutineMovePositionCamera(Vector3 LocationProject)
{
    float lerpTime = 5f;
    float currentLerpTime = 0f;

    IsCameraMoving = true;

    Vector3 startPos =  MainCamera.transform.localPosition;
    Vector3 endPos =  LocationProject;

    while (lerpTime > 0)
    {
        lerpTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        currentLerpTime += Time.deltaTime;

        if (currentLerpTime > lerpTime) 
        {
            currentLerpTime = lerpTime;
        }

    float t = currentLerpTime / lerpTime;
    t = t*t*t * (t * (6f*t - 15f) + 10f);
    //t = t*t * (3f - 2f*t);
    //t = 1f - Mathf.Cos(t * Mathf.PI * 0.5f);
    MainCamera.transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, t);

    yield return null;  
    }
    IsCameraMoving = false;
}
```

Rotate the Camera with Slerp

```
public IEnumerator CoroutineMoveRotationCamera(Vector3 LocationProject)
{
    float lerpTime = 5f;
    float currentLerpTime = 0f;

    IsCameraMoving = true;

    Vector3 relativePos =  LocationProject - MainCamera.transform.localPosition;
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos);
    Quaternion current = MainCamera.transform.localRotation;

    while (lerpTime > 0)
    {
        lerpTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        currentLerpTime += Time.deltaTime;

        if (currentLerpTime > lerpTime) 
        {
            currentLerpTime = lerpTime;
        }

    float t = currentLerpTime / lerpTime;
    t = t*t*t * (t * (6f*t - 15f) + 10f);
    //t = t*t * (3f - 2f*t);
    //t = 1f - Mathf.Cos(t * Mathf.PI * 0.5f);
    MainCamera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(current, rotation, t);

    yield return null;  
    }
    IsCameraMoving = false;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not just use gameObject.transform.LookAt to keep the camera locked on to your target object? You don't need a separate coroutine to keep the camera focussed on your target object.

Comment: Because I need something smooth, if I use a lookAt, the first move to look at the target will not be smooth :/

Comment: Use Quaternion.LookRotation to get the target rotation, and then use Quaternion.Slerp to smoothly set the rotation. Best place to put this code will be in LateUpdate or Coroutine with yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand, but it's not what I was aready doing ? I tryed to use WaitforEndOfFrame, don't work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **CoroutineMoveRotationCamera**, you need to update the **relativePostion** and **rotation** inside the while loop.

The relative position is changing while the camera is moving. Right now, your camera rotates based on the vector snapshot you took before the while loop started.

Add the following code after yield statement.

```
relativePos = LocationProject - Camera.main.transform.position;
rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos);
```

Answer (score 0):

before start coroutine, you should save the initial vars with member vars instead of function local vars