# Unity Lerp and Slerp not moving smoothly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interpolation

I created a Coroutine to handle my camera movement and direction to look and in this coroutine I have :

```
public IEnumerator MoveCameraLookAtObject(Transform _cameraTransform, Vector3 startPos, Vector3 endPos, Vector3 lookAt, float time)
{
    // Loop through a timed based situation.
    for (float i = 0f; i <= 1.0f; i += Time.deltaTime / time)
    {
        // Lerp the Movement.
        _cameraTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, i);
        // Slerp the rotation.
        Vector3 relativePos = lookAt - _cameraTransform.position;
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos);
        _cameraTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(_cameraTransform.rotation, rotation, i);
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I am actually Lerping and Slerping it looks awful and not smooth what so ever.  I am confused on what I am doing wrong as I have spent days trying to figure this out.  I looked at [Lerp and Slerp Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208980/use-lerp-position-and-slerp-rotation-together-unity) and saw that this is pretty much the same problem but the answer that person needed I already have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it would be something more like this

```
public IEnumerator MoveCameraLookAtObject(
   Transform _cameraTransform,
   Vector3 startPos, Vector3 endPos, Vector3 lookAt, float time)
{
float totalTime = 1.25f; // or whatever

float startTime = Time.time;
float endTime = startTime + totalTime;

startPos = etc etc
endPos = etc etc

startROTATION = ...
endROTATION = ...
// calculate those ONLY OUT HERE!!! not in the loop

while (Time.time < endTime)
  {
  float timeSoFar = Time.time - startTime;
  float fractionTime = timeSoFar/totalTime;

  //do NOT USE underscores in variable names
  cameraTransform.position =
    Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, fractionTime);

  cameraTransform.rotation =
   Quaternion.Slerp(startROTATION, endROTATION, fractionTime);
  yield return null; // this goes IN HERE
  }
}
```

At first test it with JUST lerping the POSITION, then try the twist!  Cheers

Comment: Thank you for the response but why would I not calculate the rotation in the loop if my object will be moving?  Since my object is moving the direction it has to look will always be changing.

Comment: Oh wait I guess I could get where the end position is and then get the angle to look at from there.  Let me try that really fast.

Comment: Dude if you're just starting out, I would encourage you to try it the "normal way" as it shows above.  You can see 100000 examples of how to do it properly (as above).  Once you have heaps of experience, you can look in to variations!!!  To be totally honest I can't be bothered explaining why you don't do that "inside the loop"  :)  You'll understand it perfectly once you've done it a few times.  Enjoy!

Comment: Yeah I know what I was doing wrong now.  Not sure why I thought I had to treat Slerp interpolation any different than how I normally use Vector3.Lerp().  Thank you for the example and taking the time to help out.  Woot!

Comment: don't forget SMOOTH STEP, the new one Unity added.  it is awesome, used everywhere