# Lerp not working as expected, jumps to value instead of smoothly proceeding to it over time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good Day,

I am working on a game and, when a certain conditions is reached I want to increase the number of particles spawned. Now instead of them just appearing all at once I elected to use lerp so that they will smoothly roll up to that value.

However despite trying my best I still cannot get this to occur smoothly and it's jumping to the maximum way too soon. 
I've posted my code with the hopes of someone pointing out the error in my ways.

```
void Update () {
    if (increaseLeaf==true)
    {

        var main = LeafStormParticleSystem.main;
        Debug.Log("here");
        main.maxParticles = (int)Mathf.Lerp(5, 150, counter);
        main.simulationSpeed = (int)Mathf.Lerp(1, 5, counter );
         counter += Time.deltaTime / 2;

        if (main.simulationSpeed == 5)
        {
            increaseLeaf = false;
        }
    }
    //counter += Time.deltaTime / 2;
    if (decreaseLeaf == true)
    {
        var main = LeafStormParticleSystem.main;

        main.maxParticles = (int)Mathf.Lerp(150, 5, decounter);
        main.simulationSpeed = (int)Mathf.Lerp(5, 1, decounter);
        decounter += Time.deltaTime / 2;

        if (main.maxParticles == 5)
        {
            decreaseLeaf = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity Lerp and Slerp not moving smoothly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845187/unity-lerp-and-slerp-not-moving-smoothly)

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues unfortunately that question doesnt help me

Comment: Can you clarify how soon is "way too soon"? How long do you expect it to take?

Comment: Can you show us where you are setting counter/decounter to 0?  the third parameter of lerp/slerp expects a value between 0 and 1.  Not to mention with the way you are transitioning from 0 - 1 will take 2 seconds, as you are not defining a speed.

Comment: @Eddge in initialization i declare all my variables including those two.     `public float counter=0.0f; float decounter = 0.0f;` but yes, it's taking 2 seconds, even less actually.  not entirely sure on the defination of the speed

Comment: @Niana your speed is the `/ 2` since you are dividing Time.deltaTime by 2, you are essentially telling it to take 2 seconds, if you want to prolong it or increase the time you can make a variable for speed, and change that /2 to `Time.deltaTime / speed` where speed is the number of seconds you want it to take.

Comment: You can check an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153617/moving-player-in-subway-surf-like-game-using-left-right-swipe/42154529#42154529) i gave about slerp, you can adjust it to lerp

Comment: @Thalthanas can I use ot to change variables? or just positions

Comment: Positions are also variables. You can get those positions(float numbers, variables) and assign them to other variables.

Answer (score -1):

When you lerp() you can do something like this `var num = new var(lerp(a,b));`

Comment: How does this fix the problem?